# Azure Active Directory Delegated Nodejs App

Tags: node.js, api, azure, authentication

I am trying to setup an app that an admin can delegate control of all other user accounts in the organisation so that I can use the calendar api of all of the users.
I followed this starting tutorial here: http://www.ozkary.com/2016/11/nodejs-passport-azure-ad-authentication.html and I filled in my azure credentials from the App Registration dashboard under Active Directory in Azure. Under Permissions I have given it everything for now.

I have set the reply URL to `http://localhost:8080/`. 
The issue I am having is after logging it, Microsoft redirects to itself, never going near my app, infact it goes here: https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf

You can see exactly what happens in this video I uploaded: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwqumSkB9VA&feature=youtu.be
I'm on the Azure free £150 trial.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code sample, it seems that you have any configuration errors about the `callbackURL`.

According to the source code in `/nodules/routes.js` file:

```
//route handler for the post authentication from identity provider
app.get('/onauth', passport.login(),
    function(req,res){
        login(req,res);   
    } 

);
```

This sample builds a route path `onauth` to handle the callback request.

So, please modify the `callbackURL` to `'http://localhost:8080/onauth'` in `modules/auth.js` file, and also set the `'http://localhost:8080/onauth'` in Azure AD application configuration.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, all good now. Out of interest do you know where the api documentation is for accessing users of the domain's mail? I tried the outlook api, but that isn't applicable from Azure app permissions.